# Is there a way to find the downvoter/upvoter of a Question/Answer?

Tags: discussion, support

Could a user after a certain reputation get the privilege to view who downvoted or upvoted his/her answer OR is it abstracted intentionally from everyone?

If abstracted what are the reasons?

Comment: What would a normal user do with that information? If you think you found a case of voting fraud, then you can flag that for a mod.

Comment: @Tom All kinds of rants, serial (revenge) voting and otherwise stalking SE community users.

Comment: @user0042 That are all flagable cases and doesn't require nullpointer (or any other user with the reputation required) to have such access to voting data.

Comment: @Tom Did you get me wrong at some point??

Comment: @user0042 Oh, yes I actually did. I thought you were listing stuff a community member could look into to evaluate further steps, like flagging for a mod after analyzing the voting, but you've listed cases of possible abuse. Well, yes I agree then, these are good reasons why a member shouldn't have the right to look into voting logs.

Comment: https://github.com/Pamblam/WhoDownvotedMe.js

Comment: @JAL It would be cool if there were statistics how often this tool was right, compared to how often it was wrong. The result of that tool isn't reliable and will only end in witch-hunts.

Comment: Uber-meta dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27534/175248

Answer (score 24):

No, there is no way to see who voted for your posts. Some (not necessarily all) Stack Exchange employees have the ability to see who voted for a particular post, but even then there are measures to try to shield them from seeing who voted for that employee's posts.

Why? Two (main) reasons.

First, there is ***no legitimate need for that information***. None. You would not gain any information by knowing who downvoted a post that you could then use in any positive way. The secret ballot is valuable precisely because it ensures people feel safe and free enough to vote honestly. (Side note: Stack Exchange employees investigating abuse of the system *do* have a valid use case for this information. They are the only exception.)

Second, ***the foreseeable uses are all bad***. The least-awful uses are on-site harassment, like pestering someone to change a vote. The worst uses are really scary. Most people who use these sites do so responsibly. Some, however, do not. Even without the ability to see who voted for or against a particular post, some users get so obsessed over internet points that they will abuse other users on the site. Worse, some users have even stalked people off-site based on perceived slights. This has even included real-life harassment, like doxing someone or calling someone's employer to demand that person be fired.

So, no, you can't ever earn this privilege. And no, that's not going to change.

Comment: When you intervene on an answer with a negative comment and a downvote at the same time, it's pretty clear for the author of the comment what happened. Some people get angry!

Comment: @curiousguy Downvotes are often a kind of other users reaction on critical comments.

Answer (score 15):

> Could a user after a certain reputation get the privilege to view who downvoted or upvoted his/her answer OR is it abstracted intentionally from everyone?

No, there isn't. Even for moderators the direct view isn't available. Stack Exchange employees maybe, but I'm not sure.

> If abstracted what are the reasons?

Up- and down-voting of posts is kept as a strictly anonymous action at all the SE sites.

The reasoning most probably is to keep anyone from the *Community* free with their decisions to vote on a posts usefulness within a Q&A framework (be it question or answer).

That well supports the community driven model for preferring useful Question and Answer pairs over too localized *"Halp me plz"* problems.